# How do I get jQuery Mobile to redirect to a  new page?

Tags: redirect, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use Jquery Mobile for a web-app, and depending on what button the user clicks, redirect them to a new web page.

Example:

A user visits `foo.com/index.php`.

When they click login it takes them to `foo.com/login.php`.

That much I've been able to figure out using:

```
<a class="ui-block-a" data-role="button" type="submit" onclick="window.location.replace('./login.php');">Login</a>`
```

When I try setting `href` to `"./login.php"`, it sends me to `foo.com/#./login.php`.

That is all well and good, but the web browser is really going to:

```
foo.com/index.php
foo.com/index.php#undefined
foo.com/login.php
```

which is causing a problem because the user has to click the back button twice.

How can I send the user from `index.php` to `login.php` without the browser trying to go to `#undefined` first?

I also tried:

```
<a class="ui-block-a" data-role="button" type="submit" onclick="window.location.replace('./login.php');" href="">Login</a>
```

but it still sends the viewer to `foo.com/index.php#` before redirecting properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:location.replace('./login.php');" class="ui-block-a" data-role="button" type="submit" >Login</a>
```

Also, have you considered just simply linking to the page normally but with an attribute of `rel="external"` ?

Comment: I tried that, but when I test it out it tries sending me to: `foo.com/#javascript:window.location.replace('./login.php');` which results in an error. I have tried `rel="external"` but that doesn't send me anywhere; when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: Try this as your link. I tried it on my test site and it worked perfectly.. `<a href="javascript:location.replace('./slider.html');" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-theme="a"  >Login</a>`

Comment: That wasn't working for me, but I added in rel="external" too and now it's working perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try making it `window.location.replace('login.php');`
or `window.location.replace('/login.php');`

Comment: They're both taking me to `#undefined` then redirecting. I also tried `location.href = 'login.php';` (and the other variations) but it's still taking me to #undefined.